# tiff2pdf is auto-rotating my image

Tags: solaris, images, conversion

I am using:

```
tiff2pdf -ox.pdf x.tif
```

to generate a PDF from a TIFF.

Why does the PDF show up as rotated 90 degrees left?

I am using tiff2pdf version 3.9.5 on Solaris.  I don't see any options to control the rotation.

Comment: There may be something triggering `tiff2pdf` to rotate the images. Have you tried running the same `tiff2pdf` command on Linux or another OS? Have you experimented with rotating your images in various ways prior to running `tiff2pdf`?  For example, if you rotate the image 90 degrees right prior to running `tiff2pdf`, does the image wind up as you really want it? Or if you rotate the image 90 degrees *left*, does `tiff2pdf` still rotate it another 90 degrees left or does it leave the image as-is?

Answer (score 0):

If I rotate the image right or left 90% then tiff2pdf creates a PDF with a matching rotation.  If I rotate the image back to its original rotation, then tiff2pdf also creates a PDF with a matching rotation.

So maybe there is something funny in the TIF, which is coming from a scanner, that gets fixed up when the TIF is rotated.

WORKAROUND:  I found that if I first use this command on the original TIF:

```
tiffset -s Orientation 1 x.tif
```

Then tiff2pdf creates the PDF correctly, even though the original Orientation tag value was already 1.  It is like updating the TIFF file somehow corrected some issue.  Though I tried using tiffset to set other attributes instead and that did not help ...

Comment: When you scan a document the scanner does not know if it's landscape or portrait, and if it's positioned the correct way. In most cases you will have to check the orientation and maybe correct the information.